# Android Intent.SetFlags() task management in IOS

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm new to IOS and I'm trying to find an equivalent way of task management in Android which looks like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(activity));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Any suggestions on what to look for?

Comment: You can look into concept of viewControllers. If you re using storbyoard for iOS then whenever you move to new viewController the instance is newly created. You don't have to deal with NewTask or ClearTask concept in iOS. For more info
https://www.appypie.com/view-controller-uiviewcontroller-ios-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ios, you can try **iOS Backgrounding**,The simplest way to perform backgrounding on iOS is to break your backgrounding requirements into tasks, and run the tasks in the background.

Here is a xamarin document which you can get more detail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks